# How to schedule task in flutter android

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, alarmmanager, schedule

I am developing an app which requires scheduling a contract with three fields: time, date, and location. This contract is created with a specific time, date, and location input and is saved in a Firestore database. Once a user accepts the contract, it's activated.

The app needs to validate if the involved parties are present at the specified location at the correct date and time. In essence, the app will cross-verify the user's current location, time, and date with the contract details. If these match, a notification indicating "You Won" will be sent. Conversely, if the requirements are not met, a notification stating "You Lost" will be delivered. This verification will only occur once when the conditions are met.

I am seeking advice on the most suitable approach to accomplish this task in Flutter.